# Spring Data Rest: Entity serialization with LAZY object cause JsonMappingException

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm getting the following Exception with a Spring Data Rest project:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
    No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) 
(through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.["content"]->test.spring.data.rest.xml.entities.Author_$$_jvstb93_1["handler"])
```

Certainly, I have some entities that have the fetch configuration = FetchType.LAZY.

I followed many instructions and links, but I still have this exception.

What I have already tried to do (with NO effetcs):

- add `@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)` in a config class that extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
- `@Override configureJacksonObjectMapper` in the same class, with also using `Jackson2DatatypeHelper.configureObjectMapper()`:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
      objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
      Jackson2DatatypeHelper.configureObjectMapper(objectMapper);
  }
  ```
- add a "`org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`" filter in the web.xml
- create a custom class that `extends ObjectMapper`, with this constructor:

  ```
  public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
      Hibernate5Module hm = new Hibernate5Module();
      registerModule(hm);
  }
  ```

  and this config:

  ```
  <mvc:annotation-driven>
      <mvc:message-converters>
          <bean
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
          <property name="objectMapper">
              <bean class="test.spring.data.rest.xml.config.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
          </property>
      </bean>
  </mvc:message-converters>
  ```

No one of the actions above has solved the problem!

How to (definitely) solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution to this annoying problem.

For every repository of the Spring Data Rest application it has to be defined a custom `@Projection`; in the projection there will be the necessaries fields.

Pay attention that if there are cycylc references between two entities, the corrispective methods of the projections have to be annotated with `@JsonBackReference` annotation (for `@ManyToOne` annotated fields) and with `@JsonManagedReference` annotation (for `@OneToMany` annotated fields), otherwise there will be a JSON loop in the JSON serialization.

In every `@Repository` annotation (or `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation) it has to be marked the *excerptProjection* property, with the custom projection.

With this management, there is no need of any other configuration, and the exception for Lazy objects finally is vanished.